# Python - Adding unique tv characters to txt file

Tags: python, list

My `names.txt` contains the following character names:

```
Peter  
Lois  
Meg   
Chris
```

But is missing the following characters:

```
Chris  
Stewie  
Bryan
```

How do I append these names to the `names.txt` file? I also need to make sure that only unique names are being added to the list (if the name already exists in the file, return a "This name is already inputted"). I am trying to scan the file line by line to decide whether to append the name (if non existent in the file) or return the "This name is already inputted".

Here is what I have so far:

```
user = input('Input character name:')

with open('names.txt','r') as characters:
    characters.readline()

for names in characters:
    names=names.strip

if names = user
    print ('This name is already inputted')
else:
    user.append()
```

Any idea how I can get my code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do. But you might want to do like this.

```
user = raw_input('Input character name:').strip()

with open('names.txt','r') as fp:
   names = [line.strip() for line in fp.readlines()]

if user in names:
    print ('This name is already inputted')
else:
    with open('names.txt', 'a') as fp:
        fp.write('\n' + user)
```

Comment: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: Thanks, it actually works. Would you know how to append the new name into the txt file in the else statement? And also, this only looks at the first line, it does not scan trough each line.

Comment: @Maverick: I updated to append user to file. `this only looks at the first line, it does not scan trough each line.` No, it does check user is unique. `if user in names:` do this.